# Batch File filter ping result and append .csv

Tags: batch-file

I made a simple script of For /L loop ending at x times with a nested loop inside it while filtering ping results.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /L %%D in (1,1, x times) do (
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('ping -n 2 -l 64 192.168.0.1 ^|findstr /c:"Packets" /c:"Minimum"') Do 
(CALL SET var=%%var%% %%A)
)
echo !var! >> pingresults.txt

endlocal
```

However, this code produces the results into a single line.

```
Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0 loss),      Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 2ms      Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0 loss),      Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 1ms      Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0 loss),      Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 2ms      Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0 loss),      Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 2ms      Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0 loss),      Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 7ms, Average = 4ms
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this one line results into multiple lines?

Besides, it would be helpful if someone can help convert and append the results into .csv with format as below:

```
  packetsent,packetrcv,packetloss,minlatency,maxlatency,avglatency,datetime
  2,2,0,2ms,7ms,4ms,datetimehere
  2,2,0,1ms,2ms,4ms,datetimehere
```

Comment: That is what the `TOKENS` and `DELIMS` options are for.

Comment: Got it. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project need to run repetitive ping for 120 loops with 50 packet count each loop.

BTW, I found the solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo This Ping Test expected to be finished within 1.6 hours...
echo packetsent,packetreceived,packetloss,minlatency,maxlatency,avglatency,timestamp > ping.csv

(for /l %%A in (1,1,120) do (
  for /f "tokens=2,4,6 delims=,=(" %%i in ('ping 192.168.0.1 -n 50 -l 64 ^| findstr "Packet Minimum"') do (
     set all=!all!, %%i,%%j,%%k
     set all=!all: =!
    
)
echo !all:~1!,!date! !time! 
set "all="

) ) >> ping.csv
Echo ***Ping Test completed.***
pause
```

Output on cmd should look like this:

```
C:\>ping.bat
This Ping Test expected to be finished within 1.6 hours...
2,2,0,25ms,26ms,25ms,Thu 10/06/2021  3:55:23.68
2,2,0,25ms,25ms,25ms,Thu 10/06/2021  3:55:24.79
2,2,0,24ms,25ms,24ms,Thu 10/06/2021  3:55:25.94
2,2,0,25ms,49ms,37ms,Thu 10/06/2021  3:55:27.05
2,2,0,25ms,26ms,25ms,Thu 10/06/2021  3:55:28.15
..........
***Ping Test completed.***
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Sorry, English is not my native language :)